# Understanding WinCE MLO file contents

Tags: windows-ce

I'm a beginner. I was trying to understand the contents of MLO file. A few bytes of the MLO header is given below. The `45 43 45 43` bytes indicate the WinCE signature. But I'm not sure about the remaining parts of the header. What part of code affects these values? I googled, but couldn't get a good resource. Any kind of guidance is welcome.

```
FE 03 00 EA 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 45 43 45 43
5C 6D FF 87 5C 6D 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a TI board?
MLO is platform-specific.
It's the first-stage bootloader. It's loaded from SD-card (or NAND flash) by the internal room that reads the MBR, searches a FAT-32 bootable partition and load that file into the internal RAM (actually it loads the file only if it's saved in the first sector of the partition, that's why you may need to format your card to update it).
XLDR initializes the external RAM, a debug serial port and then loads the second-stage bootloader ebootsd.nb0 that then can download the Windows CE image from a PC running Platform Builder or load if from the sd card.
The XLDR binary is built using RomImage, the same tool used to build the eboot and the winceimage.
That tool places a jump instruction to the image entry point in the first 32bits of the file. In this way you can load it in RAM, jump to the first location and it will jump to the real entry point.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I'm using TI board. So, does the first four bytes `FE 03 00 EA` indicate the jump instruction? If so, which bytes represent the start address of the image, that is, the address to which it has to jump?

Comment: It should point to the Startup function declared in the executable that is included in the image as nk.exe, you can find this information in the bib file used to build your XLDR. If, intead, you mean how to retrieve this information from the binary onla, I think you should check ARM's reference manual to understand this.